# Alinhamento de todos checkbox à direita

Tags: html, css

Como faço para alinhar apenas os *checkbox* à direita?

```css
html {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

form {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #4283f2;
  width:300px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:15px;
  background: #4283f2;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  border:0px;
}

legend{
  background: #4283f2;
  width:93%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  color: white;
}

hr{
  color:#4283f2;     
  background-color: #4283f2;
  height: 2px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Buscar profissão</legend>
    Alvarás e Licenças<input type="checkbox" data-id="7">
    <hr /> Ar-Condicionado e Ventilação <input type="checkbox" data-id="8">
    <hr /> Arquiteto <input type="checkbox" data-id="9">
    <hr /> Assistência Técnica em Geral <input type="checkbox" data-id="49">
    <hr /> Automação e Telefonia <input type="checkbox" data-id="10">
    <hr /> Azulejista <input type="checkbox" data-id="48">
    <hr /> Carpinteiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="11">
    <hr /> Chaveiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="59">
    <hr /> Construtora <input type="checkbox" data-id="12">
    <hr /> Dedetizadora e Controle de Pragas <input type="checkbox" data-id="13">
    <hr /> Demolição e Perfuração <input type="checkbox" data-id="14">
    <hr /> Desentupidora <input type="checkbox" data-id="15">
    <hr /> Designer de Interiores <input type="checkbox" data-id="16">
    <hr /> Drywall <input type="checkbox" data-id="58">
    <hr /> Eletricista <input type="checkbox" data-id="17">
    <hr /> Empreteiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="18">
    <hr /> Encanador de Gás e Ar Condicionado <input type="checkbox" data-id="60">
    <hr /> Encanador Hidraulico <input type="checkbox" data-id="19">
    <hr /> Engenheiro Civil <input type="checkbox" data-id="41">
    <hr /> Engenheiro Elétrico <input type="checkbox" data-id="40">
    <hr /> Feng Shui <input type="checkbox" data-id="61">
    <hr /> Fretes e Carretos <input type="checkbox" data-id="21">
    <hr /> Gesseiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="22">
    <hr /> Instalador e Montador <input type="checkbox" data-id="23">
    <hr /> Jardineiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="24">
    <hr /> Limpador de Caixa D’agua <input type="checkbox" data-id="62">
    <hr /> Limpador de Piscina <input type="checkbox" data-id="43">
    <hr /> Limpeza e Higienização <input type="checkbox" data-id="25">
    <hr /> Marceneiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="26">
    <hr /> Marido de Aluguel <input type="checkbox" data-id="42">
    <hr /> Marmorista <input type="checkbox" data-id="47">
    <hr /> Mestre de Obras <input type="checkbox" data-id="45">
    <hr /> Monitoramento e Segurança <input type="checkbox" data-id="27">
    <hr /> Paisagista <input type="checkbox" data-id="28">
    <hr /> Pedreiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="29">
    <hr /> Persianas e Cortinas <input type="checkbox" data-id="51">
    <hr /> Pintor <input type="checkbox" data-id="30">
    <hr /> Poço Artesiano <input type="checkbox" data-id="31">
    <hr /> Rede de Proteção <input type="checkbox" data-id="32">
    <hr /> Reformas em Geral <input type="checkbox" data-id="57">
    <hr /> Restauração de Pisos <input type="checkbox" data-id="33">
    <hr /> Serralheiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="34">
    <hr /> Tapeceiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="35">
    <hr /> Técnico em Edificações <input type="checkbox" data-id="46">
    <hr /> Telhadista <input type="checkbox" data-id="44">
    <hr /> Toldos <input type="checkbox" data-id="52">
    <hr /> Vidraceiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="36">
    <hr />
    <div>
      </br>
      <button type="submit">Confirmar</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Como faço para alinhar apenas os checkbox à direita ?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a propriedade float?

Comment: @BrunoSpy , cara não tinha pensado nisso! Solucionou meu problema, obrigado mano !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça um container/div ajustado e faça uma regra geral para os **checkbox**

Veja:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso mano, deu certo ! Obrigado !

Comment: De nada ! fico feliz por ajudar :)

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar um ***"float: right;*** que todos ficarão à direita.

```css
html {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

form {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #4283f2;
  width:300px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:15px;
  background: #4283f2;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  border:0px;
}

legend{
  background: #4283f2;
  width:93%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  color: white;
}

hr{
  color:#4283f2;     
  background-color: #4283f2;
  height: 2px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Buscar profissão</legend>
    Alvarás e Licenças<input type="checkbox" data-id="7">
    <hr /> Ar-Condicionado e Ventilação <input type="checkbox" data-id="8">
    <hr /> Arquiteto <input type="checkbox" data-id="9">
    <hr /> Assistência Técnica em Geral <input type="checkbox" data-id="49">
    <hr /> Automação e Telefonia <input type="checkbox" data-id="10">
    <hr /> Azulejista <input type="checkbox" data-id="48">
    <hr /> Carpinteiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="11">
    <hr /> Chaveiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="59">
    <hr /> Construtora <input type="checkbox" data-id="12">
    <hr /> Dedetizadora e Controle de Pragas <input type="checkbox" data-id="13">
    <hr /> Demolição e Perfuração <input type="checkbox" data-id="14">
    <hr /> Desentupidora <input type="checkbox" data-id="15">
    <hr /> Designer de Interiores <input type="checkbox" data-id="16">
    <hr /> Drywall <input type="checkbox" data-id="58">
    <hr /> Eletricista <input type="checkbox" data-id="17">
    <hr /> Empreteiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="18">
    <hr /> Encanador de Gás e Ar Condicionado <input type="checkbox" data-id="60">
    <hr /> Encanador Hidraulico <input type="checkbox" data-id="19">
    <hr /> Engenheiro Civil <input type="checkbox" data-id="41">
    <hr /> Engenheiro Elétrico <input type="checkbox" data-id="40">
    <hr /> Feng Shui <input type="checkbox" data-id="61">
    <hr /> Fretes e Carretos <input type="checkbox" data-id="21">
    <hr /> Gesseiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="22">
    <hr /> Instalador e Montador <input type="checkbox" data-id="23">
    <hr /> Jardineiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="24">
    <hr /> Limpador de Caixa D’agua <input type="checkbox" data-id="62">
    <hr /> Limpador de Piscina <input type="checkbox" data-id="43">
    <hr /> Limpeza e Higienização <input type="checkbox" data-id="25">
    <hr /> Marceneiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="26">
    <hr /> Marido de Aluguel <input type="checkbox" data-id="42">
    <hr /> Marmorista <input type="checkbox" data-id="47">
    <hr /> Mestre de Obras <input type="checkbox" data-id="45">
    <hr /> Monitoramento e Segurança <input type="checkbox" data-id="27">
    <hr /> Paisagista <input type="checkbox" data-id="28">
    <hr /> Pedreiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="29">
    <hr /> Persianas e Cortinas <input type="checkbox" data-id="51">
    <hr /> Pintor <input type="checkbox" data-id="30">
    <hr /> Poço Artesiano <input type="checkbox" data-id="31">
    <hr /> Rede de Proteção <input type="checkbox" data-id="32">
    <hr /> Reformas em Geral <input type="checkbox" data-id="57">
    <hr /> Restauração de Pisos <input type="checkbox" data-id="33">
    <hr /> Serralheiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="34">
    <hr /> Tapeceiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="35">
    <hr /> Técnico em Edificações <input type="checkbox" data-id="46">
    <hr /> Telhadista <input type="checkbox" data-id="44">
    <hr /> Toldos <input type="checkbox" data-id="52">
    <hr /> Vidraceiro <input type="checkbox" data-id="36">
    <hr />
    <div>
      </br>
      <button type="submit">Confirmar</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```